# data table is not working in angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I'm trying to apply dataTabe in the my table but I'm not getting the proper data table.

I'm first populating the data in angular table the I'm applying the dataTable, without dataTable I'm getting the proper result;

My controller:

```
 MyService.getData(function (response) {
    if (response.data.success) {
        $scope.items = angular.copy(response.data);
            $timeout(function () {
                var table = $("#test").dataTable();
            }, 200)

    } else {
        $scope.items = [];
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="test">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 10%">Id</th>
            <th style="width: 20%">Group Name</th>
            <th style="width: 20%">Created Date</th>
            <th style="width: 20%">Updated Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody ng-repeat="item in items">
        <tr>
            <td>{{item.userGroupId}}</td>
            <td>{{item.groupName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.createdDate}}</td>
            <td>{{item.updatedDate}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

screenShots:

> Before Appling DataTable:

[image]

> After Appling dataTable:

[image]

I have searched in dataTable doc and google also But I didn't found any clue.Please help me.

Comment: You should really consider using angular datatables (dataTables wrapped into directives, services and factories)  - if you can make a myjson.com out of your `items`, I would be happy to make a demo.

Comment: @davidkonrad hey I'm using the jquery data table everywhere  and It's working fine for others screen. Only on one screen I'm getting this issue for one issue I can't change everywhere.

Comment: well you are using it incorrectly and there is an angular module already available for this plugin. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for your valuable suggestion, but we can't revert back in this stage.So please suggest me what I can do in this situation.

Comment: You could pass data directly to the plugin and initialize without using `ng-repeat`. What you are currently doing is just not stable guessing that you need 200 ms to wait. You should be doing this in a directive. Letting the plugin build the html will also be far more efficient anyway

Comment: @charlietfl, exactly - and OP do not _have_ to use angular datatables everywhere, just in this case where there is a race condition (or something like that, the problem is a little bit vague) - since the angular module share the same CSS and code for dataTables, there should be no difference in appearence.

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl and davidkonrad for your valuable Suggestion.